# disable php ODBC Connection Pooling

Tags: php, odbc, unixodbc

I'm trying to disable this:

[image]

[The microsoft docs tell me to set `Pooling = No` in my `/etc/odbcinst.ini` and "reload the drivers"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/connection-pooling-microsoft-drivers-for-php-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks). How exactly do i do that? I'm using fpm and restarting the fpm service doesn't do the trick.

Current `/etc/odbcinst.ini`

```
[ODBC]
Pooling=No

[PostgreSQL]
Description=ODBC for PostgreSQL
Driver=/usr/lib/psqlodbcw.so
Setup=/usr/lib/libodbcpsqlS.so
Driver64=/usr/lib64/psqlodbcw.so
Setup64=/usr/lib64/libodbcpsqlS.so
FileUsage=1

[MySQL]
Description=ODBC for MySQL
Driver=/usr/lib/libmyodbc5.so
Setup=/usr/lib/libodbcmyS.so
Driver64=/usr/lib64/libmyodbc5.so
Setup64=/usr/lib64/libodbcmyS.so
FileUsage=1

[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]
Pooling=No
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.5.so.2.1
UsageCount=1
```

Comment: What does the relevant section of your `odbcinst.ini` file look like?

Comment: @MatsLindh i've edited my answer to include my current ini file

Comment: I'm interested in the "restarting driver" part, please.